# How to (dynamically) change meta tags before the site is scraped in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, web-crawler, seo

I've built a web app using Angular 2, and need to make it more SEO-friendly. I want to dynamically change the values of the head. meta tags in different routes, **before** the site is scraped by Facebook, Instagram, and Twitter's web scraping robots.

I am able to update the meta tags dynamically as I want, by using the @angular/platform-browser [Meta Service](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta):

```ts
this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: title }, "property='og:title'");
this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:image', content: image }, "property='og:image'");
this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content: desc }, "property='og:description'");
```

So the HTML head is updated correctly both on initialization (from ngOnInit), and on router navigation (from a Subscriber to `router.events` in `app.component.ts`)

My issue is that social media's web scraping bots are retrieving the static src/index.html no matter what, before the Angular app adds ANYTHING, including content from router-outlet.

Here is the raw response from Facebook's crawler when scraping my URL:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="no-NB">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Title</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="title" content="My title">
  <meta name="description" content="My description.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="All, Of, My, Keywords">
  <meta property="og:title" content="My Og Title">
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/ogimage.jpg">
  <meta property="og:description" content="My Og Description.">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1e146e9a97.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.da6e4981b1413a95ffba.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills.6282a28eb8950eb48467.js" defer></script><script src="main.74eff1edffffe134e66e.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it retrieves a response from my site before anything is loaded - AKA the original, static index.html.

Is there a way around this, or do I actually have to run multiple apps with their own index.html in the same project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've built a web app using Angular 2, and need to make it more SEO-friendly. I want to dynamically change the values of the head. meta tags in different routes, before the site is scraped by Facebook, Instagram, and Twitter's web scraping robots.

This is actually a common limitation of SPA's (Single Page Applications), as the HTML meta-tags are generated on the client. [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069501/single-page-applications-and-open-graph)

Basically, the crawler from Google/FB can't see the tags as it doesn't actually *render* the page, it only requests the raw HTML and sees the basic `index.html` that Angular starts with. You can simulate what the crawler sees by using [curl](https://curl.se/) to request your page: `curl http://myangular.site/about`, which will output the HTML that the crawler will index.

There's a few solutions to this:

- Server Side Rendering (SSR)

  - Manually render pages [like this article](https://medium.com/forcit/seo-for-single-page-applications-8543619e1d0c)
  - Use the official package [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal)
- Don't use a static server

  - When `/about` is requested, serve the `index.html` file and add the `meta` tags onto it.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll avoid the official Angular Universal package to keep the original code base and dynamic rendering for real users, and implement the general method from the article you linked. Seems it best serves it's purpose by targeting only bots.

Comment: @Alex how can you distinct real users from scrapers? I have this same problem and honestly don't know how to go about it despite knowing what needs to be done. I'm new to networking and web servers.

Comment: @DFSFOT I ended up remodeling my application to use SSR (server side rendering) instead of default CSR (client side rendering, or browser rendering), using Angular Universal (https://angular.io/guide/universal). This way content is built and rendered on the server, before the content is served to the client. So no matter if it's a bot or a person, the initial response will contain the fully built html